# Interpeting Mediation R package with binary mediator and binary outcome

Tags: r, mediation

I have a question concerning he Mediation R package concerning the interpretation of the estimates.

I'd like to interpret the results of the Mediation package output. Let's say I have a binary mediator and a binary outcome and the ACME (average) estimate is 0.016 (p<0,05). How can I interpret this estimate?

According to the the documentation "all estimated effects are expressed as the increase in probability", but what does it actually mean ?